# Uniform convergence of power series expansion of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

If $f$ is a holomorphic function on the unit disc $\{z:|z|<1\}$, we can write $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$. Can we be sure that this series converges uniformly on compact subsets of the disc, or do I need to add assumption that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n<\infty$ somewhere?

Comment: You need to add the assumption that the series converges uniformly on compact subsets, since this is not ensured by simple holomorphicity. Surely if the series converges somewhere on the boundary of the disk, then you'll be fine. However I think there are some strange holomorphic functions where this does not happen.

Comment: @Crostul: power series always converge uniformly on compact subsets of their disc of convergence, and the disc of convergence of the power series expansion of a holomorphic function is always at least large enough to reach the boundary of the domain on which the function is defined. No strange exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can be sure of that.  Note that a compact subset $K$ of the disc is contained in $\{z: |z| \le r\}$ for some $r < 1$ (because the continuous real-valued function $|z|$ attains a maximum on a compact set).  Take $r < s < 1$.  Now $|a_n| s^n$ must be bounded in order for $\sum_n a_n s^n$ to converge, so there is $B$ such that $|a_n z^n| \le B (|z|/s)^n \le B (r/s)^n$ and the series converges uniformly on  $K$.

Comment: Quick question to your first sentence. If $K$ is assumed to be arbitrary compact subset of the disc, does the value of $r<1$ depend on the choice of $K$?

Comment: Yes, of course.